# A nice recurrence sequence

Tags: recurrence-relations, computer-science, order-theory, recursive-algorithms, recursion

I want to find general solution for recurrence:

$a_n=7a_{n-1}-10a_{n-2}+4n$

with suppose $c_1, c_2, c_3$ is constant.

I need some tutorial or solution on this challenging recurrence.

Comment: Why do you need $c_1,c_2,c_3?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is of the form
$$
a_n=c_1w_1^n+c_2w_2^n+c_3n+c_4,
$$
where $w_1,w_2$ are the roots of
$$
x^2-7x+10=0
$$
i.e., $w_1=2,\,w_2=5$.

The part $=c_1w_1^n+c_2w_2^n$ corresponds to the *homogeneous* recurrence relation:
$$
A_n=7A_{n-1}-10A_{n-2}.
$$

For the *inhomogeneous* part $c_3n+c_4$, we obtain
$$
c_3n+c_4=7(c_3(n-1)+c_4)-10(c_3(n-2)+c_4)+4n,
$$
which implies
$$
c_3=7c_3-10c_3+4,
$$
and hence $c_3=1$, while
$$
c_4=7c_4-10c_4 -7+20,
$$
and thus $c_4=13/4$. Altogether
$$
a_n=c_12^n+c_25^n+n+\frac{13}{4}.
$$

Comment: In a second order recursion we have at most two free variables, i.e., no $c_3$ undecided.

Answer (score 1):

It's a linear difference ( similar to differential ) equation for the sequence $a_n$, write it as

$$a_n - 7\, a_{n-1} + 10 \,a_{n-2} =4n$$

The idea is to write the sequence $a_n$ as a sum of two sequence $a'_n$ and $b_n$ where $a'_n$ satisfies the homogenous equation

$$a'_n - 7\, a'_{n-1} + 10\, a'_{n-2} = 0$$

and $b_n$ is a particular solution of the equation

$$b_n - 7\, b_{n-1} + 10\, b_{n-2} = n$$

Let's find one such $b_n$, search for a polynomial of degree not larger than $1 +2 = 3$ ($1$ the degree of $n$ and $2$ the order of the recurrence ( involves $2$ previous terms).

$$b_n= p n^3 + q n^2 + r n + s$$

Plug in the expressions for $b_n$,$b_{n-1}$, $b_{n-2}$ into the previous equation and identify the coefficients of $n^3$, $n^2$, $n$, $1$. You get a system in $p$,$q$,$r$,$s$ with unique solution $p=q=0$, $r=1$, $s=\frac{13}{4}$ and so 
$$b_n = n + \frac{13}{4}$$

Now for $a'_n$ that satisfies the homogenous equation, write it as a combination of other sequences that also satisfy it for obvious reasons. Those are some special geometric sequences $\lambda^n$$ the condition being

$$\lambda^n - 7\, \lambda^{n-1} + 10\, \lambda^{n-2} =0$$

for all $n$, equivalently (divide by $\lambda^{n-2}$)

$$\lambda^2 - 7\, \lambda + 10=0$$

There are two possible values for $\lambda$, the roots of the above quadratic equation.

$\lambda= 2$ or $\lambda = 5$ and any combination

$$a'_n = c_1\, 5^n + c_2 \,2^n$$ will be a solution of the homogenous equation ( and these will be all of them).

Therefore $a_n = a'_n + b_n$, that is

$$a_n = c_1\, 5^n + c_2\, 2^n + n + \frac{13}{4}$$